# What's Google Analytics user/active user/new user/define?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a question regarding the active users definition in the active users report.

According to the official explanation (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6171863?hl=en)

1-Day Active Users: the number of unique users who initiated sessions on your site or app on January 30 (the last day of your date range).
7-Day Active Users: the number of unique users who initiated sessions on your site or app from January 24 through January 30 (the last 7 days of your date range).

Can I interpret sessions here as "at least one session"(one or above)?  If so,  the 7-Day Active Users can be users who only viewed one session during the last 7 days. How can this metric indicate the "returning users"?

Should I sessions as " more than one" (two or above), which seems to make more sense?

Another question: As 7-Day Active Users counts into the active users from the last 7 days (including today), so it should include all 1-Day Active Users . By the same logic, the 14-Day Active Users should include all 7-Day Active Users, and the 30-Day Active Users should include all 14-Day Active Users. Am I correct?

If I am correct, then it will never happens that 1-Day Active Users are more than 7/14/30-Day Active Users.

What does the below sentence from the explanation page mean?

"In cases where you have a lot of 1-Day Active Users but the numbers drop off for longer term users"

Does it mean that 1-Day Active Users stabilizes/increases while the long term users decrease? So it's about comparing the trend, not the absolute active user number?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited fo https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Users reports are bit tricky to understand in GA, basically it depends on the date range you are selecting.

Q1: GA considers a user as active if he had at least one session for that day irrespective of whether the user is new or returning or he had more than a single session.

Q2: No, all 1-Day Active Users are not included in 7-Day Active Users. For example a user had a session today and also on the 7th day then he'll be counted only once because in the selected date range at least one session is only considered.